# Labelling outliers with ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to label outliers with ggplot. Regarding my code, I have two questions:

1. Why does it not label outliers below 1.5*IQR?
2. Why does it not label outliers based on the group they are in but instead apparently refers to the overall mean of the data? I would like to label outliers for each box plot individually. I.e. the outliers for Country A in Wave 1 (of a survey), etc.

A sample of my code:

```
PERCENT <- rnorm(50, sd = 3)
WAVE <- sample(6, 50, replace = TRUE)
AGE_GROUP <- rep(c("21-30", "31-40", "41-50", "51-60", "61-70"), 10)
COUNTRY <- rep(c("Country A", "Country B"), 25)
N <- rnorm(50, mean = 200, sd = 2)

df <- data.frame(PERCENT, WAVE, AGE_GROUP, COUNTRY, N)

ggplot(df, aes(x = factor(WAVE), y = PERCENT, fill = factor(COUNTRY))) +
  geom_boxplot(alpha = 0.3) +
  geom_point(aes(color = AGE_GROUP, group = factor(COUNTRY)), position = position_dodge(width=0.75)) +
  geom_text(aes(label = ifelse(PERCENT > 1.5*IQR(PERCENT)|PERCENT < -1.5*IQR(PERCENT), paste(AGE_GROUP, ",", round(PERCENT, 1), "%, n =", round(N, 0)),'')), hjust = -.3, size = 3)
```

A picture of what I have so far:
[image: Outlier Label]

[image]

I appreciate your help!

Comment: I wonder if [**this question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33524669/labeling-outliers-of-boxplots-in-r) is helpful for you.

Comment: Thanks! I saw this when googling the problem. I was hoping to solve the problem without adding an additional column to my data frame.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47740448/cannot-place-count-label-at-boxplot-whisker-with-outliers-present/47741716#47741716) may also be helpful.

Comment: And [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47777159/ggplot2-geom-boxplot-annotating-counts-without-computing-them-in-advance/47777280#47777280) regarding your second question, about grouping.

Comment: Apparently my first and second question go together. And it seems like what I have been trying to do can only be done by adding another column to the data frame because of the way ggplot works. I'll give this a try! Thanks for pointing me to these resources!

Comment: Which version of ggplot2 are you running? I cannot reproduce your figure.

Comment: I use the latest version (2.2.1) and I have loaded the following libraries: haven, readr, ggplot2, dplyr, stringr

Comment: I solved the problem using [JasonAizkalns's] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33524669/labeling-outliers-of-boxplots-in-r) function. Even though I had to add an extra column to my data, it was the most convenient way for me to do it. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want `IQR` to be calculated by country, you need to group the data. You could probably do it globally(i.e. before you send the data to `ggplot`) or locally in the layer.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(x = as.factor(WAVE), y = PERCENT, fill = COUNTRY)) +
  geom_boxplot(alpha = 0.3) +
  geom_point(aes(color = AGE_GROUP, group = COUNTRY), position = position_dodge(width=0.75)) +
  geom_text(aes(group = COUNTRY, label = ifelse(!between(PERCENT,-1.3*IQR(PERCENT), 1.3*IQR(PERCENT)), 
                                                paste(" ",COUNTRY, ",", AGE_GROUP, ",", round(PERCENT, 1), "%, n =", round(N, 0)),'')), 
            position = position_dodge(width=0.75),
            hjust = "left", size = 3)
```

Comment: The line `data=. %>% group_by(COUNTRY)` has no effect as far as I can tell, and I also wouldn't know why it should have one. The currently released ggplot2 version does not respect groupings from dplyr.

Comment: I see. `group=COUNTRY` in aesthetics is enough. I corrected the answer.

Comment: Actually, as far as I can tell, even that is not needed. I'm not sure why the OPs result looks the way it does.

Answer (score 2):

Adding the `group` aesthetic to `geom_text` and modifying the `ifelse` test should do what you want.

Setting `group = interaction(WAVE, COUNTRY)` will restrict the calculations to within each boxplot, and the outliner test needs to include a call to `median(PERCENT)`.

```
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(42)

PERCENT   <- rnorm(50, sd = 3)
WAVE      <- sample(6, 50, replace = TRUE)
AGE_GROUP <- rep(c("21-30", "31-40", "41-50", "51-60", "61-70"), 10)
COUNTRY   <- rep(c("Country A", "Country B"), 25)
N         <- rnorm(50, mean = 200, sd = 2)

df <- data.frame(PERCENT, WAVE, AGE_GROUP, COUNTRY, N)

ggplot(df) +
  aes(x = factor(WAVE),
      y = PERCENT,
      fill = factor(COUNTRY)) +
  geom_boxplot(alpha = 0.3) +
  geom_point(aes(color = AGE_GROUP, group = factor(COUNTRY)), position = position_dodge(width=0.75)) + 

  geom_text(aes(group = interaction(WAVE, COUNTRY),
                label = ifelse(test = PERCENT > median(PERCENT) + 1.5*IQR(PERCENT)|PERCENT < median(PERCENT) -1.5*IQR(PERCENT),
                               yes  = paste(AGE_GROUP, ",", round(PERCENT, 1), "%, n =", round(N, 0)),
                               no   = '')),
            position = position_dodge(width = 0.75),
            hjust = -.2,
            size = 3)
```

[image]